# ¿Cómo ocultar etiquetas de un DrawerNavigation React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

Esta es la primera vez que publico una pregunta y estoy buscando solucionar este problema que tengo, es un proyecto personal en el que llevo meses trabajando pero tengo este problema y no sé cómo solucionarlo, alguien que me ayude

¿Cómo puedo ocultar y eliminar el espacio de una etiqueta de Drawer?

como se ve en la imagen oculta la etiqueta pero el espacio sigue ahí, ¿cómo puedo quitar ese espacio? Necesito poner esa etiqueta en el drawer. ¿Algún consejo para solucionar ese problema?

Solo necesito ponerlo en el drawer esconderlo y sin tapar ni ocupar un espacio importante en el drawer.

Lo necesito porque navegaré a esa ventana más tarde, pero ¿cómo puedo ocultar la etiqueta de la pantalla de inicio sin que ocupe un espacio dentro del drawer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

the code

app.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import {
  NavigationContainer,
  getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';


import Agregar from './ventanas/agregar';
import Inicio from './ventanas/inicio';
import Lectura from './ventanas/lectura';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const NavigationDrawerStructure = (props) => {
  //Structure for the navigatin Drawer
  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    //Props to open/close the drawer
    props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleDrawer()}>
        {/*Donute Button Image */}
        <Icon name = "navicon" style={{width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5}}
         size={25}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const getHeaderTitle = (route) => {
  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Feed';
  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Inicio':
      return Inicio;
    case 'Agregar':
      return Agregar;
  }
};


const InicioScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Inicio">
      <Stack.Screen name="Inicio"  component={Inicio}
        options={({route}) => ({
          headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#3f5ed1', //Set Header color
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold', //Set Header text style
          },
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const AgregarScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Agregar" screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => (
          <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation}/>
        ),
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#3f5ed1', }, //Set Header color
        headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
        headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold', },//Set Header text style
      }}>

      <Stack.Screen name="Agregar" component={Agregar} options={{title: 'Agregar Producto', //Set Header Title
      }}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};


const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
          itemStyle: {marginVertical: 5},
        }}>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="InicioScreen"
          options={{drawerLabel: () => null}}
          component={InicioScreen}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Lectura"
          options={{drawerLabel: 'Agregar producto'}}
          component={Lectura}
        />
  
      </Drawer.Navigator>

      
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: En español por favor

Comment: Por favor, traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario lo más probable es que termine cerrada.

Comment: Perdón, ya traduci la pregunta me gustaría que alguien me ayude con este problema que tengo con el Drawer de React-native

Answer (score 0):

Es muy facil crea tu propio panel:

```
    import MyPanel from '...'
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" 
                 drawerContent={MyPanel} >
                 //drawer screens
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Al crear tu propio panel puedes crear tu propia logica de como se mostrara los botones ,etc basado en un stado por ej. logeado o no. Puedes usar reactcontext para pasar props globales

```
           <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" 
                     drawerContent={(props) => (<MyPanel {...props} />)} >
                     //drawer screens
            </Drawer.Navigator>
```